# Making use of inlines in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I seem to be having a lot of trouble making use of Django Admin inlines. Django seems to want relationships to only be expressed in a certain way in order to allow inlines on objects. For example, I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    email = models.OneToOneField("EmailAddress")
    address = models.OneToOneField("Address")

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    """A warehouse _has_ an address."""
    name = models.CharField(..., default="[Unnamed Warehouse]")
    address = models.OneToOneField("Address")

class Donor(models.Model):
    """A donor _is_ a person."""
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)

class Recipient(models.Model):
    """A recipient _is_ a person."""
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)

class Sponsor(models.Model):
    """A sponsor _is_ a person."""
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)

class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..., default="Home")
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_default = models.BooleanField()

class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..., default="Home")
    street_address = models.TextField()
```

Here's how I'd like to represent `Donor` in the admin:

```
First Name: [person.first_name            ]
Last Name:  [person.last_name             ]
Email:      [person.email.email           ]
Address:    [person.address.street_address]
```

Due to project requirements, I need to keep these fields in the `Person` class. (ie: a `Person` could be a `Donor` **and** a `Sponsor` at the same time, and there's no use in duplicating that data in the DB.)

It seems that Django's admin site is really hardcore about its requirements for doing inlines and it refuses to let me edit a `Donor` by editing its `person` as an inline.

Django, it seems, requires me to move all of my relations to the opposite end of things, so that `Person` would essentially have 3 useless fields: `donor`, `recipient`, and `sponsor`, and `Address`(!) would have to have `warehouse` and `person` declared directly on them. This really doesn't make any sense to me.

Why is Django's admin system so against doing inlines on models like these, and is there a hack to get around it without having to write views and forms and without having to reverse all of the relationships I've written?

Comment: Have you tried inheriting Donor, Recipient and Sponsor from Person? In this case you'll only need to make some machinery to allow creating different objects for same Person.

Comment: Could you give me a "for-instance" as an answer? Ie: how to set up the models, how to write the admin forms and the inlines, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *Partial Solution*

As @ilvar suggested above, I simply made an inheritance hierarchy for `Person` descendants:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class Donor(Person):
    ...

class Recipient(Person):
    ...
```

This causes all of the fields from `Person` to appear in the admin for `Donor`, which is what I want :)

Unfortunately, things are still not working with the `Person.email` relation to `EmailAddress`:

```
class EmailInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = EmailAddress
    fields = ('email',)

class DonorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

When I go to add a new `Donor`, I see the all-too-familiar error message:

```
Exception at /admin/core/donor/add/
<class 'core.models.EmailAddress'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'core.models.Donor'>
```

Ugh. This is getting old. How can I create an inline for `EmailAddress` on the `Donor` model admin?

Comment: `EmailAddress` should have a FK to `Person` to use inlines. Or you can manually create field for email in form and process it. If you need few fields - you even can make your own `EmailAddressField` derived from `MultipleField` and put all your needed fields there. So you avoid hacking form's __init__() or save(), it's useful when same inline should be used in few forms.